# PHP able to read Object list of a webservice generated by Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services

I wrote a webservice in asp.net C# that return a list of a class, Now I want to check that a program that wrote in PHP can read my object or not,

If your answer is yes, would you tell me how and if the answer is no what should I add to my code?
I asked this question because when I test my webservice I cannot see any xml, I am worry my webservice not working properly.

Please advice me in case if I want to show my result in xml format what should I do?

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<CustomerData> getFMSCustomerName()
    {
        string[] cols = {"V_CUST_CODE", "V_CUST_NAME"};

        ArrayList CustomerList = (ArrayList)db.Select(cols, "table1", "", "order by V_CUST_NAME");

        List<CustomerData> cd = new List<CustomerData>();
        foreach(DataRow dr in CustomerList)
            cd.Add(new CustomerData(dr["V_CUST_CODE"].ToString(), dr["V_CUST_NAME"].ToString()));

        return cd;
    }
```

My customer class:

```
public class CustomerData
{
    private string _V_CUST_CODE;
    private string _V_CUST_NAME;

    public String V_CUST_CODE
    {
        get
        {
            return this._V_CUST_CODE;
        }
        set
        {
            this._V_CUST_CODE = value;
        }
    }
    public String V_CUST_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return this._V_CUST_NAME;
        }
        set
        {
            this._V_CUST_NAME = value;
        }
    }


    public CustomerData(String V_CUST_CODE, String V_CUST_NAME)
    {
        this.V_CUST_CODE = V_CUST_CODE;
        this.V_CUST_NAME = V_CUST_NAME;

    }

    public CustomerData() { }
}
```

My out put is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <ArrayOfCustomerData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://123.23.45.34/sms/" />
```

Comment: May you supply C# webservice response example?

Comment: I check that one but in those example I just saw they read webservice again in c#, not in PHP, is it same? I have no idea, can we create List with generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can. Please [read this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bramveen/archive/2009/09/03/using-php-to-connect-to-an-asp-net-2-0-webservice.aspx) for more detail.

This [blog](http://forums.asp.net/t/887892.aspx/1) also good. Hope this help.

You can convert object to xml by using  this `Using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`
I think, this  [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/400803.aspx/1) directly can not help to this answer. I hope, this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but still I didnt get my answer, my question is if I just share my class with PHP developers is it enough for them to read object of my webservice? most of the example are just with int or string parameter, I am using class...

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer json_seri = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   CustomerData cs_list = 
          (CustomerData)json_seri.DeserializeObject("{ \" _V_CUST_CODE\":\"some data\" }"); reference to this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

Comment: I found it very hard, I dont want to restart the server and also I dont have VS in server to follow installation steps

Comment: I cannot find Package Manager Console in VS2008. some one help me please